# Haskell ReplicateM IO

Tags: haskell, io, parse-error, replicate

I'm trying to create a function which allows the user to input a list of strings. The function takes the length and allows the user to input length-1 more lines. Then each line is checked to ensure it is the same length as the original line. However, I'm having a few problems and that I can't find a solution to.

The problems are that I can input more than count-1 lines and the length isn't being calculated as I expected.. for example if I input ["12","13"] and then ["121","13"] the error is given, although they are the same length!

```
read :: IO [Line]
read = do
  line <- getLine
  let count = length line
  lines <- replicateM (count-1) $ do
    line <- getLine
    if length line /= count
    then fail "too long or too short"
    else return line
  return $ line : lines
```

Line is of type String.

readLn gives a parse error.

Comment: Your code works fine for me (except indentation issue with if-then-else block).

Comment: As clarification, is the first line of input meant to be a number that tells you how many other lines there are? Or is that number actually based on the length (number of characters) of the first line as you have written here?

Comment: The strings `["12","13"]` and `["121","13"]` don't have the same length; the latter has one more character than the first. Do you want to read strings, or lists of strings?

Comment: The number is based on the length of the first line, although looking at the comments I think an issue could be with my use of length. Is it based on characters? In prelude length ["12","13"] and ["121","13"] both return 2.

Comment: As Daniel Wagner reports in his answer, from `getLine` you get a `String`, so length is the number of characters in the string. To try this in ghci, try `length (show ["12","13"])`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're getting confused about the difference between getting a line as a `String` and reading/parsing a line of input as a custom type. You are using `getLine`, which always returns exactly the `String` that the user types. Compare:

```
Prelude> fmap length getLine
["12","13"]
11
Prelude> length "[\"12\",\"13\"]" -- explanation of the 11
11
Prelude> fmap length (readLn :: IO [String])
["12","13"]
2
Prelude> length ["12", "13"] -- explanation of the 2
2
```

As demonstrated here, you probably want to use `readLn`, which first gets a line of input and then parses it with `read`.

```
-- defined in the Prelude
readLn = do
    s <- getLine
    return (read s)
```

If I modify your code to include the imports and definitions below:

```
import Control.Monad
type Line = [String]
```

...and to call `readLn` instead of `getLine`, then I can type the literal lines `["12","13"]` and `["121","13"]` without errors.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I see now - although my type Line = String and I can't change it to [String] as it is used in various other functions I've defined. So when using readLn in this instance a parse error is returned

Comment: @gdrules: so change your other functions.  Or add some glue code.